# What does setting Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.Confined do?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class LockState : MonoBehaviour
{
    public bool lockState = false;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        if(lockState == false)
        {
            Cursor.visible = true;
        }
        else
        {
            Cursor.visible = false;
            Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.Confined;
        }
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (lockState == false)
        {

        }
        else
        {

        }
    }
}
```

I want to do a simple lock state of the mouse cursor.
If locked don't show the mouse cursor and locked it and if unlocked then show and unlock.

I will use the states : Locked and None but what the Confined should do ? Should I use it too ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## From [the documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/CursorLockMode.html):

> #### Properties
>
> **None**  |   Cursor behavior is unmodified.
> **Locked**    |   Lock cursor to the center of the game window.
> **Confined**  |   Confine cursor to the game window.

Answer (score 4):

Its keeps the cursor from leaving the game window/screen. From [the documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Cursor-lockState.html):

> When Confined, the cursor behaves normally with the exception of being confined to the view. For example, if the application is running in a window, the mouse cursor cannot leave the window in Confined mode.